# Xdomain ajax html scrape is loading images when wrapping data respose in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrape

I'm trying to make a cross domain request to fetch the html, cache it and then iterate over the cached html to pull out data and eventually put it on the page. This is working but it wastes http reqs.

The problem is that once I wrap `data.responseText` with jquery `$(data.responseText)` it then goes and makes 40 http requests to pull in images.

Is it possible to just cache the a jquery html object inside of a variable without the extra image requests?

Using this x-domain hack here:
https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

```
getPage: (baseUrl) ->
  console.log("beg scraping")
  $.ajax
    url: baseUrl,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "",
    success: (data) =>      
      frag = data.responseText
      @page = $(frag) # cache in object, now 40 extra reqs.
      # this doesn't work, only returns images
      #@page = $(frag).find('[src]').remove()
      console.log "Scraping done"
    error: (status) ->
      #window.pushError("getPage error: #{status}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can quickly search the text and remove all `<img>` elements. Then create the jQuery object:

```
var no_images = $(data.responseText.replace(/<img[^>]*>/g, ''));
```

Here's another thread you may find helpful:

[load an HTML string into jQuery without requesting images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006216/load-an-html-string-into-jquery-without-requesting-images)

Comment: Doh, I never thought about using a regex before wrapping it...doh! Thanks for the link, I searched on here over and over but I must have been querying wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: No worries! I've been there. Occam's razor disappears out the door when you've been staring at a problem for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want to keep the images without automatically requesting them, you can replace the src attribute with something that wont automatically be fetched. e.g.

```
page.replace(/src/g, 'source');
```

This will keep the src reference under 'source' instead, and wont automatically load the image.